# How to repair a block paved drive shifted by vehicle use

Tags: repair, uk, driveway, paving

I have a block paved drive at my house in the South East of the UK which has been in place for about twenty years.

Where we turn our vehicles before reversing into the garage the turning force has displaced an area of paving stones. We try to avoid dry steering and keep the car moving slowly while moving the steering wheel. This started when we bought a Land Rover Discovery, a 2583 Kg car, which we have now sold. While we had that car I paid a drive repair company to work on it, they relaid the pavers and added the line of blue edging stones where previously there was nothing. The movement continued, so I had them return to amend the work under warranty. They relaid it again, using a dry mix of sand and cement powder as they again relaid the pavers and added more concrete behind the blue stones. They then hosed it down to wet the cement powder and we left it unused for a week.

[image: Drive A]
[image: Drive B]

As you can see the movement has persisted. What would be the optimal amendment to resolve this for good, please?

To note, I'm making any redress with the company that did the work out of the scope of this question.

Comment: Would probably put a proper cement/concrete pad in that area, if you want to keep turning the tires there.  Maybe with the pavers inbeded in the cement.

Comment: The problem is, that when a car is stationery and you turn the steering wheel, that creates *extreme* force on the roadway.  **That force is hidden from you** because you have power steering, but I have manual steering on my 2000lb car (~900kg) and boy howdy!  Even 1-2 mph of movement greatly reduces wheel effort / stress on road.  You need to figure something out here because this is not sustainable as you are trying to do it.

Comment: Generally we avoid dry steering, the car is moving slowly when turning. I’ve driven without power steering and know what you mean! I’ll amend the question.

Comment: Are those two black pipes to drain water from the roof?  Possible they are making the ground near the problem area extra wet/soft, and adding to the problem.

Comment: They are, you may be right - though I’ve never noticed it being a wet area, and the plants in that border sometimes need watering. Which itself may be a problem!

Comment: It may not be the wheels turning at all.  It looks like the ground is sinking there.     Maybe a broken drain pipe?   Some rotted wood?  I would dig down about three feet and then fill it up with several layers of pack (Class 5, roadbed gravel, crusher rock) compressing and tamping each layer.